# Scala Type mismatch, expected: List[NotInferedA], actual: List[Int]

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I'm trying to execute this piece of code inside a Scala Worksheet (using Intellij):

Scala version I'm using is 2.11.12

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

def tail[A](l: List[A]): List[A] =
  l match {
    case Nil => sys.error("tail of empty list")
    case Cons(_, t) => t
  }

val a = List(1,2,3)
tail(a) //should be List(2,3)
```

The compiler gives me a 'Type mismatch, expected: List[NotInferedA], actual: List[Int].

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are combining your own **List** with Scala's **List**, specially this one `val a = List(1,2,3)` is a Scala's **List**. My advice is to use different names, like `MyList`, `MyNil`, etc. Also, you can not create an instance of your **Lists** as `MyList(1, 2, 3)` because that method is not defined. You can create it, or just construct your List as `MyCons(1, MyCons(2, MyCons(3, MyNil)))`, alternatively, you may create an operator similar to `::` to make it more aesthetic like `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: MyNil`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `List` class is missing a companion object. Calling `List(1,2,3)` constructs a default Scala `List`, not your list.

You need to add something like this (replace `???` with the real constructor functionality, probably using some recursive function):

```
object List {
  def apply[A](s: A*) = ???
}
```